# How to pass a prop to my child route?

Tags: reactjs

I have a child route that I want to pass locationId prop to.

I tried just adding locationId={locationId} to my Route but that didn't work.

```
return (
  <div>
      <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/users/:userId`} component={CardsShowView} />
  </div>
);
```

Is it possible to pass this prop somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/users/:userId`} render={() => 
<CardsShowView locationId={locationId}/>} />
```

You can use the `render` prop.

If you actually want the location, you can do it like this.

```
<Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/users/:userId`} render={(props) => 
<CardsShowView locationId={props.location}/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the locationId as a param with the Route.

`<Link to={`url/${locationId}`}>`

in your Route: 
`<Route path="url/:locationId component={CardsShowView}`

you can access the params in your child component by using `this.props.params.locationId`